# How to edit the Table of Contents in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, evince

How can I edit the Table of Contents (also called Outline in Evince) in a PDF file?

For example, if I see a typo in the Table of Contents, how can I edit it to fix it myself? Or if I want to add more items in a Table of Contents, how can I do it?

I know how to do it in Windows with Foxit and Adobe Reader, but I don't see any options to edit the Table of Contents in Evince or Okular. Is there any way to edit it with either of these document readers, and if not what other reader or software can I use in Linux to edit it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but it is not possible. If you want to edit the toc you can ether use command line tools like **pdftk** and many others, or if you like to have a gui based solution simple install the 3rd party program like [MasterPdf](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/).

Comment: Thanks, both work. I'll leave [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029451/613269) here because I needed it to install pdftk—it's not available on the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [jpdfbookmarks](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/) (Java) and, more recently, [PdfMod](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/PdfMod); both successfully.

The second one is in the official Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```